# Remove first forward slash in a link?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to remove the first forward slash inside link formatted like this:

```
/directory/link.php
```

I need to have:

```
directory/link.php
```

I'm not literate in regular expressions (preg_replace?) and those slashes are killing me..

I need your help stackoverflow!

Thank you very much!

Comment: best place to get to know preg_replace is of course [php documentation](http://php.net/preg_replace)
I'd suggest checking [general preg (pcre) documentation](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) as well.

Comment: re Good learning resource - I've learned a lot by using The Regex Coach: http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/ (free for personal and commercial use)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Just because nobody has mentioned it before:

```
$uri = "/directory/link.php";
$uri = ltrim($uri, '/');
```

The benefit of this one is:

- **compared to the [`substr()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955212/remove-first-forward-slash-in-a-link/955233#955233):** it works also with paths that do not start with a slash. So using the same procedure multiple times on an uri is safe.
- **compared to the [`preg_replace()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955212/remove-first-forward-slash-in-a-link/955223#955223):** it's certainly much more faster. Actuating the regex-engine for such a trivial task is, in my opinion, overkill.

Comment: darn. as soon as I saw this question I was hoping I'd get to suggest this. :) +1

Comment: `trim` will remove multiple slashes too, so `trim('//foo/bar')` becomes 'foo/bar' which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 7):

```
preg_replace('/^\//', '', $link);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can you point me to a good learning resource for preg_replace?

Comment: can also be written as `preg_replace('#^/#', '', $link);` which may be more readable

Answer (score 3):

If it's always the first character, you won't need a regex:

```
$uri = "/directory/link.php";
$uri = substr($uri, 1);
```

Comment: You don’t need to specify the length.